# Can the Aharonov-Bohm experiment also be described by conditional probablilties, like the simple double slit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, bohmian-mechanics, aharonov-bohm

The most attractive description of the double slit experiment for me is that in [Beltrametti and Cassinelli's book](https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9781107340725).$^{[1]}$ The essence of their description is the following.
[image]

**Beltrametti-Cassinelli description of the double-slit experiment** - They somehow treat the $x$ position classically and suppose that the time of the collision to $S_2$ is independent of the position of the collision. They also adopt a reference frame in which the particle has no velocity along the x-axis. So the state space for the one-dimensional configuration space (i.e., along the y-axis) is $\mathfrak L^2(\mathbb R)$.

They take the state of the particle in the absence of the screens as a density operator $D$ and calculate the density operator $D'$ in the presence of screen $S_1$ as the density operator of the conditional probability in state $D$ of finding the particle in the interval $E$ at time instant $\tau$ with respect to the condition of finding it in $F_1\cup F_2$ at time instant $0$, that is, they take
$$p_{D'}(\pi_E)=p_D(\pi_{E}(\tau)|\pi_{F_1\cup F_2}(0))\tag 1$$
where $\pi_E(\tau)$ is the projection belonging to the statement "at time instant $\tau$, the particle is located in $E$" and $\pi_{F_1\cup F_2}$ to "at time instant $0$, the particle is located in $F_1\cup F_2$". They use the Heisenberg picture, so that
$$\pi(t)=U_t^{-1}\pi(0)U_t\tag 2$$
with the evolution operator $U_t$, and the state $D$ is independent of time. The conditional probability is defined as
$$p_D(A|B)=\frac{\mathrm{tr}(DBAB)}{\mathrm{tr}(DB)}\tag 3,$$
that is,
$$D'=\frac{BDB}{\mathrm{tr}(DB)}\tag {3'}.$$
At a point they take $D$ a pure state, that is, $D=D^\psi:=\psi\otimes\psi$ with a $\psi\in\mathcal H$ having unit norm).
The story ends with
$$p_D(\pi_E(\tau)|\pi_{F_1\cup F_2}(0)) = \int_E |U_r(C_1\psi_1(y)+C_2\psi_2(y))|^2 dy
\tag 4$$
where $\displaystyle \psi_i=\frac{\chi_{F_i}\psi}{\|\chi_{F_i}\psi\|}$ and $\displaystyle C_i=\frac{\|\chi_{F_i}\psi\|}{\|\chi_{F_1\cup F_2\|}}$ and $\chi_F$ is the characteristic function of the set $F$.

**Question** - The [Aharonov-Bohm experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect) is a slightly modified version of the double slit. Is this Beltrametti-Cassinelli kind of description applicable to the Aharonov-Bohm experiment too? Has this ever been attempted? If yes and not, then why not? Wouldn't be it more simple than working with path integrals?

[image]

---

$^{[1]}$ Enrico G. Beltrametti and Gianni Cassinelli - *The Logic of Quantum Mechanics*, Addison-Wesley, 1981, pp. 283 - 285

Comment: Quanta don't have positions and they don't have velocities. I do not understand what you are trying to do here. The entire argument doesn't match any physically workable definition of quantum that I have ever seen.

Comment: @FlatterMann This is an approximation. As written above, x coordinate is treated classically while y by quantum. mechanics.  It's not my idea, see the reference given. I note that this kind of notion of conditional probability isn't clear to me, but it works here.

Comment: There is no approximation in which quanta have position and velocity. Moreover, the double slit is not even a good example for quantum mechanics. It's no even a unitary process.

Comment: x coordinate is classical. No quanta. Only y coordinate is quanta. It has a probability distribution in a given state.

Comment: Classical corpuscles don't have diffraction functions. Only quanta of energy have those... but quanta don't have location. A single quantum doesn't have a probability distribution and a state, either. Only the quantum mechanical ensemble has those. It seems to me that there is something rather strange going on in this argument that mixes concepts that are completely unrelated.

Comment: In my opinion, double slit is the simplest example in quantum mechanics. And yes, it is a unitary process. This process is responsible for spreading the probability after the slits from the slits to the whole y axis.

Comment: Let's take this to chat, if you want to. Technically the double slit is not even quantum mechanics. Planck's constant is not in it and we aren't analyzing multi-quantum correlations like in the case of entanglement experiments, either. The double slit diffraction function is perfectly classical. Young had an explanation for it in 1801, a hundred years before quantum mechanics was even conceived of. And like I said, the scattering of a real double slit is not even unitary, i.e. the formalism doesn't even apply to it without ad-hoc modifications.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150964/discussion-between-mma-and-flattermann).

Comment: This looks like an extraordinarily complicated way to write something very simple. Sure, one can always inflate the size of notation as much as desired, but why?